# Cannot get a SIMPLE HISTOGRAM to plot in Python 3.7 Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.7, histogram2d

Below is the error code I received as I am trying to do a Histogram from the DF "code" and the column ("Age")

```
code['Age'].plt.hist()
1
code['Age'].plt.hist()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-2117f9d17105> in <module>
----> 1 code['Age'].plt.hist()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180 
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'plt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hist function directly from matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(code['Age'])
plt.show()
```

This should work. You can also do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

code['Age'].hist()
plt.show()
```